# Looking for the least used employee 2017

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this: Service_Done

```
Employee_ID  Grooming_ID     Date_Serviced:                                                               
1               3                  1/23/2016                                                  
2               4                  04/4/2017
3               3                 07/24/2017
```

My code looks like this:

```
 SELECT Employee_ID
FROM Service_Done
WHERE Employee_ID = (SELECT Grooming_ID, Count(Employee_ID) FROM Service_Done 
AND year(Date_Serviced) = 2017;
```

I run this code and it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: The code cannot work because your where clause is not returning a scalar value, i.e. your LHS is Employee_ID and your RHS is a table with two columns. Could you please describe what you intend to achieve, or what your result needs to be.

Comment: I am trying to look for the employee that provided the less service during 2017.  The answer is supposed to be an employee ID

Comment: Okay, could you please describe how you arrive at - "less service during 2017". As in, what is the criteria? What is Grooming ID?

Comment: What about employees who did nothing?

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (Employee_ID  INT, Grooming_ID INT,    Date_Serviced DATE);
INSERT INTO T VALUES                                                               
(1        ,       3     ,   '2016-01-23'),                                                      
(2        ,       4     ,   '2017-04-04'),     
(3        ,       3     ,   '2017-07-24'),
(3        ,       3     ,   '2017-07-24'),
(3        ,       3     ,   '2017-07-24'),
(4        ,       3     ,   '2017-07-24')
;

SELECT Employee_ID #,COUNT(*) SERVICES
FROM T
WHERE  year(Date_Serviced) = 2017
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID 
ORDER BY COUNT(*)  LIMIT 1;

+-------------+
| Employee_ID |
+-------------+
|           2 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The employee_id returned is indeterminate in the event of a draw.